# git p4 sync operation failure

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I am using "git-p4" script for migration from p4 to GIT. clone operation is failing due to large number of change list (about 5 million). So I am trying to perform incremental import operation:
I tried to clone for first run then sync operation. I tested with small changes list.

First run:

```
git p4 clone //depot/f1/f2/f3/ere@17888479,17918050 -v
```

Second run:

```
git p4 sync //depot/f1/f2/f3/ere@17918051,17918064 -v
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-p4", line 3677, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-p4", line 3671, in main
    if not cmd.run(args):
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-p4", line 3429, in run
    die("fast-import failed: %s" % self.gitError.read())
  File "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-p4", line 122, in die
    raise Exception(msg)
Exception: fast-import failed: warning: Not updating refs/remotes/p4/master (new tip 85c94d84335bb1441a7f959b384729b2a4d633f4 does not contain 3222bdc29799d1fe5fff91c36524481b1469f1d9)
```

Comment: Are you using --detect-branches?

Comment: No, I am using same command as mentioned in the description.

Comment: Try playing around with "--max-changes" and "--changes-block-size" arguments available in git p4 clone, instead of using changelist ranges.

Comment: Thanks, I found a workaround. I cloned changelist ranges to different repository (empty repository) and pushed one after the other through merge operation.

Comment: Don't forget to describe it in an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:
 - Create a directory and clone codes with a change list ranges.
git p4 clone //depot/f1/f2/f3/ere@17888479,17918050 -v
 - Push codes to GIT repository. You can use given script on below link to move code with history.
https://gist.github.com/emiller/6769886
 - Create another directory (empty repository) and clone codes with incremental change list ranges.
 - Pull codes from GIT and merge it with codes in local repository.
 - Resolve conflict and push it after commit

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar case described recently](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190227094926.GE19739@szeder.dev/) during a `git-fast-import` process

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), `git-p4` should be more robust around that edge-case.

See [commit 43f33e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43f33e492af65d008045ee0695d0f17434e8c3c9) (30 Jan 2020), and [commit 19fa5ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19fa5ac333134fc3aa1e462780c4690177474ade), [commit 6026aff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6026aff5bbe7389fa276188237b58afbef1b07ff), [commit ca5b5cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca5b5cce6290351f8cb63ee4ff466ed4a2285319), [commit 4c1d586](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c1d58675d07296adb2cf40b4b1c24f8d7a20d75), [commit 5c3d502](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c3d5020e66caad0418b5696ba0f3d013641fcdd), [commit 837b3a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/837b3a6376804ec70b88f06c3f702a38c59196c3) (29 Jan 2020) by [Luke Diamand (`ldiamand42`)](https://github.com/ldiamand42).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4a77434](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a77434bc83c07c17ddc321b3892337b5533eda1), 14 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6026aff5bbe7389fa276188237b58afbef1b07ff): cleanup better on error exit
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Luke Diamand</sup>
>
> After an error, `git-p4` calls `die()`. This just exits, and leaves child processes still running.
>
> Instead of calling `die()`, raise an exception and catch it where the child process(es) (`git-fastimport`) are created.
>
> This change does not address the particular issue of `p4CmdList()` invoking a subchild and not waiting for it on error.